# django Search inside files

Tags: python, django, search

I am building a file hosting application. I want to build a search form which can search inside static files (Something like grep). I have been through haystack but it didn't search inside static files. Is there any module for the same.

Comment: I don't think there is an app. You should use `grep` kind of tools to do search. You can use `subprocess` module to issue OS commands from Python/Django.

Answer (score 0):

You could just open the files and literally search through the contents.

```
for line in open("file"):
if "search_string" in line:
    <do something>
```

If speed is of the essence (which I imagine is so), you could just prepare the data beforehand and stick with haystack with your preferred search server.